# Does R's glm function use randomness?

Tags: r, least-squares, linear-model

Does R's `glm` function use randomness in any way? Exercise 8(d) in chapter 5 (section 5.4) of [*An Introduction to Statistical Learning*](https://www.statlearning.com/) (a free book) seems to indicate that it does because it has the reader change the random seed and fit a new model (with the same data).

Remark: I'm not using (and don't use) R, so I couldn't test it.

Comment: Per the documentation [1], it uses iteratively reweighted least squares (IWLS) to fit the model -- might be a place to start.


  [1]: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html

Comment: Thanks @dlid. Looks like the only place where there could be any randomness is in the initial "guess" of the approximation algorithm (as in Newton's method). R has a separate IWLS function and its documentation indicates that its implementation is from a research paper, "page 46 of Suveges (2007)".  I checked that out and didn't see any obvious randomness there either. (I might've missed it.)

Comment: Try running it twice with the same inputs and see if the outputs are [identical](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/identical.html).

Comment: Thanks @Ben. That's what I meant I cannot do when I said "I couldn't test it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no randomness in the fitting algorithm or in the initialisation for the built-in link and family.  `glm` accepts user-defined link/family combinations and these could in principle use randomness.